# jQuery select value undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Ok, I have a really simple problem that is definetly easy to solve, but I can't find the solution. 
I have a function that get's called when I press the button. This function should do something, but firstly alert the values I typed in. I got a textarea for `reviewText` and a select for `review`

Now, I want to alert those values, as soon as I press the button

```
echo '<select name="rating" size="1">';
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    if($i == 1)
        echo '<option value="' . $i . ' Star" name="' . $i . ' Star" id="' . $i . ' Star">' . $i . ' Star' . '</option>';
    else
        echo '<option value="' . $i . ' Stars" name="' . $i . ' Stars" id="' . $i . ' Stars">' . $i . ' Stars' . '</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';
```

The problem now comes in the JavaScript-function. 
So far I have this

```
function addReview(itemid, userid)
{
    var reviewText = $('#reviewText').val();
    var rating = $('#rating').val();

    alert(reviewText);
    alert(rating);
}
```

It shows me the value of the textarea, but not of the select. Why? What am I doing wrong? I also tried to delete all values, ids and names from the options but that didn't help either. What is the problem?

Comment: `$('#SELECT_BY_ID')` select by id

`$('.SELECT_BY_CLASS_NAME')` select by class name

`$('SELECT_BY_TAG_NAME')` select by tag name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `#rating` selector selects an element with `id="rating"` not `name="rating"`

Put `id="rating"` additionally to your select tag (preferred), or select it as `select[name="rating"]` (not recommended but will work as well).